# How to load JSON data from an AJAX call in AngularJS Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-bootstrap

I would like to create the following. Have a button that when clicked opens a dialog/modal from Angular Bootstrap[1 which will then display a loading indicator while the app fetches json data from the server then have that data be presented in the dialog content.

I am thinking that I would make a dialog template which has the parsing code for the json data i.e. some ng-repeat to present it as a list for example.

I am unclear as to:

1. Where in the process do I add a load indicator (let's say spin.js). I'd want to be able to refer to some div inside the dialog template from the controller I assume?
2. At what point do I make my ajax call
3. How to pass that data to the template and have it parsed

Comment: What do you mean by "URL"?

Comment: I mean that I would like to insert the result of an ajax call. I was thinking that I would open the modal with a spin load indicator then do my $http call and add the result to the inner content. Just not real clear on the full process though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to manually load the template into the dialog. The `$dialog` service from AngularUI accepts both a static template or a template url. That URL can return anything, it'll just perform a `GET` request via an AJAX call and fill the dialog with whatever data is returned. That request is cached locally so that next calls are supposed to be faster than the first one.

Here's a simple snippet to get you started:

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap.dialog'])
    .controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $dialog, $window) {
        $scope.open = function() {
            var options = {
                backdrop: true,
                keyboard: true,                    
                controller: 'DialogCtrl', // the dialog object will be inject 
                                          // into it
                templateUrl: 'path/to/view' // can be either a static file or 
                                            // a service that returns some data
            };
            var dialog = $dialog.dialog(options);
            dialog.open().then(function(result) {
                if (result === 0) {
                    $window.alert("Cancel pressed");
                }
                else if (result === 1) {
                    $window.alert("OK pressed");
                }
            });
        };
    })
    .controller('DialogCtrl', function($scope, $http, dialog) {
        // Here you can put whatever behavior the dialog might have
        $scope.close = function(result) {
            dialog.close(result);
        };

        // Loads some data into the dialog scope
        $http.get('/path/to/service')
            .success(function(response) {
                $scope.items = response;
            });
    });
```

**Main HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <button ng-click="open()">Open dialog</button>
</div>
```

**View HTML**

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3>Title</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <!-- Renders the data loaded by the controller -->
  <p ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item }}</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn" ng-click="close(0)">Cancel</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="close(1)">OK</button>
</div>
```

This [Plunker script](http://plnkr.co/edit/MIR7fcQhAA1XnKJ7cT8r?p=preview) demonstrates all of the above.

**Update**: I've updated the example code in order to demonstrate how you can dynamically change the dialog box content.

Comment: So let's say I wanted to call a url that return some JSON data then wanted to ng-repeat it in my view.html. How would I handle that?

Comment: All you have to do is call that URL from the dialog controller, load the returned JSON into the dialog scope and change the dialog template so it can render the data. I've updated the post to demonstrate that.

Answer (score 0):

> "modal is a directive that reuses $dialog service to provide simple
>   creation of modals that are already in your DOM without the hassle of
>   creating partial views and controllers.
>
> The directive shares $dialog global options."

Check the bootstrap dialog options below is the url :

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dialog